# Select arrays, subqueries, and multiple row results

Tags: mysql, arrays, join, subquery

I am trying to create a single query to gather information from multiple tables. Here's the basics to understand my needs:

The information gathered from table one is simple. One row per result. This is the main result, so let's just make the variables p.id, p.name, and p.street Call the table props p.

The information from the second table, which I will call events e will also be simple. There will be one event per prop, and it joins on p.id = e.pid. From that table, we need e.event_start.

Here's where it gets tough. The third table has two layers of multiple results: Let's call it features f. Features has four columns in it: fid, pid, feature, and desc. We join it on p.id = f.pid.

What I need are results that come out like this:

```
[0] PID
[1] name
[2] street
[3] event_start
[4] features
    [0] lighting
        [0] red
        [1] orange
    [0] sound
        [0] guitar
        [1] drum
        [2] keyboard
```

Now, I have been searching online for solutions, thinking I could do this with subqueries in the select:

```
   SELECT p.id, p.name, p.street, e.event_start, (SELECT f.feature)
```

using joins, of course. From simple to difficult, I have not gotten it to work. I've looked at GROUP_CONCAT, but that's definitely not giving me what I need...it makes a single string, etc.

Is there any way to do this in one single query? If so, advice on how is very welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood; you have three tables p,e,f and you need to get values from these tables using JOIN. Is it this way:

```
SELECT p.id,p.name,p.street,e.event_start,f.feature,f.desc
                             -- i'm not sure you need features from third table based on conditions. Use CASE WHEN in the select
                             --sorry didn't understand what you mentioned
FROM p JOIN e ON p.id=e.pid
       JOIN f ON p.id=f.pid
WHERE                        --state your conditions
```

Comment: Sort of, but not quite. The method you describe will give us multiple rows: a separate row for each feature/value combination. What I need is one row with the pid, all the other information from the first two tables, and every feature/value combination from the features table. One row per p.id

Comment: Is it row or column? For values from different column to appear in the same column you can use concat: CONCAT(f.feature,',',f.desc) in the select clause.

Comment: I ended up using GROUP_CONCAT with CONCAT_W separating with commas and semicolons, and it worked.